# Bootstrap .row class correct usage

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I've been using Bootstrap for 4 months and there's something I am still not too sure about.

What is the correct use of the row class ? Here are two examples

First example : each row only contains 12 columns

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Second example : each row is basically similar to container class, just removing left and right padding. As you can see, this row is equal to 24 columns, so it will create 2 rows anyway because 12 is the maximum.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't get misunderstood with the output you get with the second solution. First one is correct. Using the second solution will eventually lead to problems in complex pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the default Bootstrap styles, there is whitespace (`margin-bottom`) between rows. If you want that space, use a `row`. If you do not want whitespace between the elements inside the `row`, you add as many `col`s as you like, and they will wrap as you've seen.

Column wrapping is absolutely a feature of Bootstrap; it's what makes responsive layouts possible.

Lastly, you can use a `row` to force a "hard wrap", if you've got a `row` with fewer than 12 columns, and you wish the next element to always be on another row.

Answer (score 0):

You are overthinking things. the row class was only made to handle up to 12 columns. The second is technically incorrect use. The first way is the way you should implement `row`.

EDIT:

After seeing wrapping in the documentation, I would say the bootstrap framework is made to accommodate this, as columns that are too wide are already wrapped, but it is still best to try to keep it to 12 cols. If you need to though, you can use more. It would depend on what you would need as the developer.

(made my comment an answer, as it was more appropriate as one)

Comment: the problem is column wrapping is actually in the official documentation http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping and not labelled as incorrect use, so it's a bit disorientating

Comment: Huh, so it is. I would say in that case, the bootstrap framework is made to accommodate this, as columns that are too wide are already wrapped, but it is still best to try to keep it to 12 cols. If you need to though, you can use more.